# How to know what object threw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

```
try{
  return A[key1].Keys.Union(B[key1].Keys).ToList();
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException ex)
{}
```

The task is to find all keys from A[key1] and B[key1] and to "unite" them. 
But A[key1] and B[key1] can throw an exception and I wonder how can I know whether A object,or B object threw those exception?

Comment: You should use `TryGetValue` to get a value for a key that may or may not exist.

Comment: @RufusL he has, it's `KeyNotFoundException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code block you posted, that's impossible. You could however try to get their values before or check that they exist:

```
if(!A.ContainsKey(key1)) // A didn't have key1
  return null; // Maybe throw exception?
if(!B.ContainsKey(key1)) // B didn't have key1
  return null; // Maybe throw a different exception?
return A[key1].Keys.Union(B[key1].Keys).ToList();
```

Or the slightly faster (since they key has been searched already)

```
type a, b; // Type must be the type that A[key1] and B[key1] contains
if(!A.TryGetValue(key1, out a)) // A didn't have key1
  return null; // Maybe throw exception?
if(!B.TryGetValue(key1, out b)) // B didn't have key1
  return null; // Maybe throw a different exception?
return a.Keys.Union(b.Keys).ToList();
```